# how to get path of html file in php email

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I want to add a file path to the content of an email.
I created an html email template file.
I have tried the following code but it not works.

```
$content ="".file_get_contents(basename(__DIR__).'/welcome-email-template.html');

wp_mail($to, $subject, $content);
```

Comment: 1. Are you using wordpress? 2. Have you tried opening the template file in your browser? Match that against an echo of the basename(__DIR__).'/welcome-email-template.html' before send mail. In short, you're probably not getting the path correct.

Comment: So what does your http server's error log file say what the issue is?

Comment: Yes i am using wordpress. And i opened the file in my browser and it is working. I have the template file in the same dir of functions file.

Comment: I am executing the project remotely not locally

Comment: Think you need to check this and edit your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I changed basename(**DIR**) to TEMPLATEPATH

```
$content ="".file_get_contents(TEMPLATEPATH.'/welcome-email-template.html'); wp_mail($to, $subject, $content);
```